# Stop laptop from suspending when closing lid in lightdm

Tags: power-management, lightdm

How do I stop my laptop from suspending when closing the lid under lightdm - the power management settings in xfce or gnome 3 does not seem to apply when the window manager is not running.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

At the bottom of `/etc/UPower/UPower.conf`, set `IgnoreLid=true`.

Comment: Thanks a bunch, this works! Tested to set it and unset it again on 12.04

Comment: doesn't the: "At the bottom of /etc/UPower/UPower.conf, set IgnoreLid=true." prevents any action when the lid is closed for all users?

Comment: This worked for me after a restart.

Comment: I had to undo this change: `lightdm` was not starting anymore after I set `IgnoredLid=true`. I'm on Ubuntu 14.04.

Comment: This does not work (currently).  I have this option set in UPower.conf, and lightdm still suspends the machine when the lid is closed.

Comment: @alex.forencich Can confirm, this doesn't work. However, this answer does: https://askubuntu.com/a/1140362/1011478

Answer (score 4):

Run

```
sudo vim /usr/share/polkit-1/actions/org.freedesktop.upower.policy
```

and replace the `yes` to `no` in the `allow_active` tags and replace from "yes" to "no" for inactive tags.

either

- reboot
- exit your X session, alt+ctrl+f1, and run `sudo /etc/init.d/lightdm restart`

Note: I just tested it, and restoring the values back to `yes` did not restore the previous functionality... no clue why.

Also, lightdm will still try to sleep, but will be denied. So every time you open the lid, you will get a message box telling the sleep/suspend failed.

this will also prohibit active suspend/sleep

...yet another annoyance that gnome3 brings us

Comment: Thanks for the research, looks like it cant be completly sovled without the hickups you mention

Answer (score 3):

Run

```
gksudo gedit /etc/systemd/logind.conf
```

Uncomment

```
HandleLidSwitch=suspend
```

And change `suspend` to `ignore`.

Worked for me in 16.04.

Comment: This is perfect! I was starting my laptop with lid closed, external monitor hooked on and ac power, and seconds after I got to the login page it would go in suspend right away. (I used variant HandleLidSwitchExternalPower)

Answer (score 1):

Changing `allow_active` to `no` disable suspend for everything.
I can't find better way to solve this but to switch to another console by pressing <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> and then close the lid.